# JavaScript - Google Charts - Redraw on drag and drop

Tags: javascript, google-visualization

Is it possible to recall the chart.draw function on drag and drop of elements.

I want to drag charts around the dashboard, but when I have tried to to implement this, it has just copied the chart and all interactivity has been lost.

Comment: Forgot to add the code - http://jsfiddle.net/w6aag/1/

Comment: were you ever able to implement this functionality? I am looking to do the same thing and would love some advice if you have any to share.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do that, but your chart objects have to be in scope for your drag-n-drop event handlers.